# How do I access the 'mx' or 'fl' namespaces in a Flex Builder Actionscript Project?

Tags: actionscript, namespaces, flexbuilder, swc

How do I access the `mx` or  `fl`  namespaces in a Flex Builder Actionscript Project?

Do I need to include a certain .swc file?

I can't seem to find which one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just import mx, but be aware your project will carry a ton of weight from the Flex framework. All of the l package classes are in your Flash installation folder and need to be added as a source folder in your compiler paths in FB.

If you just want to use the easing function than the solution is easier than importing any of the MX packages. When I use GTween in AS3 projects I simply cut-n-paste the functions into my own static classes.

Comment: thanks. it wouldnt let me add just 'mx'. i had created an 'actionscript project' and turned out i had to add the 'Framework.swc' file to compile paths. i'm actually just wanting the easing equations (to use with gTween) and aren't using anything from Flex

Answer (score 0):

```
import mx.effects.easing.*;
```